# Prove that a convex curve C has tangent lines everywhere except at countably many points.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Today, I was faced with the following question:

> Suppose E was a convex region in the plane bounded by a curve C. Show that C has a tangent line except at a countable number of points.

Since the next question asks me to show that every convex function $f:I\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a derivative everywhere except at a countable number of points, I am trying to avoid proving the first statement using derivatives. However, I have no idea even how to attempt this question because I don't know how I can characterize a curve that bounds a convex region. I have done some reading and it led me to a field I know nothing about so I am pretty much stuck here. The question gives the hint of considering circles, triangles and so on but I don't know where that is supposed to lead me because I can easily think of convex regions which are not polygons (or convex regions with 2 points without a tangent line, for example). Even when I tried to use derivatives to solve the problem I had no idea how to proceed, so I would greatly appreciate some help.

EDIT: After noticing that there's probably no way around using derivatives, I would like to point out that answers using derivatives are welcome too.

Comment: Possibly a silly question: how are you defining a tangent line to such a curve? You say you want to do it without derivatives, so do you have a derivative-free way of doing so? Doing it with derivatives is a little fraught, given that the differentiability of the curve function will depend on the parameterisation.

Comment: @TheoBendit Not a silly question at all, you are correct in that it's weird to talk about the tangent line without mentioning the derivative. However, I'm trying to avoid using derivatives because the next question makes explicit use of derivatives so perhaps I need to use this result without derivatives and apply it to the question explicitly asking for use of derivatives. I added an edit though; so in case anybody wants to use derivatives to answer the question that's fine too.

Comment: I can't really get past the problem of using derivatives as well. You could, for example, make a parameterisation that is nowhere differentiable. If we assume the parameterisation is injective, then perhaps we could proceed. It doesn't sound like this question was especially well thought out. On the other hand, the next question is well-posed, and can be answered without too much hassle, without using this question.

Comment: @TheoBendit Could you elaborate on your idea please?

Comment: I think Theo is saying this problem is hard to well-pose, as written

Comment: Though, @TheoBendit let’s agree a “curve” is a continuous image of a circle. How do you know it’s possible to use a nowhere differentiable parametrisation of this curve? I know the differentiable functions (at at least one point) are nowhere dense in $C[0,1]$, but I’m not sure how that allows us to trace the curve with a nowhere differentiable map

Comment: But some people use “curve” to mean, a continuously differentiable function $I\to\Bbb R^k$. That doesn’t make sense for this problem though

Comment: The Rademacher theorem states that any locally Lipschitz function is ae. differentiable. A little overkill for convex functions perhaps, but certainly sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The key concept in answering your question is the *[subdifferential](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Subdifferential)* of the function. Whilst a derivative of a convex function does not need to be defined at every point, its subdifferential is defined at every point. You can think of subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ as the closed interval between the left derivative $f'_-(x)$ of the function and the right derivative $f'_+(x)$ of the function $f(x)$. This interval is degenerate, i.e. consisting of a single point, when $f'_-(x)=f'_+(x)$, in that case $f$ is differentiable at $x$ (in other terms, it has a tangent).

A convex function has nonempty subdifferential at every interior point $x$ of $I$, so both left and right derivatives of $f$ are defined and $f'_-(x)\leq f'_+(x)$. What is more, the functions $f'_-(x)$ and $f'_+(x)$ are increasing thanks to the convexity of $f$. Consider the set $D$ of points $x$ at which $f'_-(x)\neq f'_+(x)$. Then the open intervals $(f'_-(x),f'_+(x)), x \in D$ are disjoint. Since each open interval contains a rational number and there are only countable many rational numbers, the set $D$ can be at most countable.

**Let me clarify the last argument:** Every $x\in D$ can be associated to an open interval $I(x)$ in a way that the intervals $I(x), x\in D$ are disjoint. Each of these intervals contains a rational number (in fact infinitely many of then, but that does not matter in this proof), pick any of them and denote it $r(x)$. So we have that $r(x)\in I(x)$ and $r(x)$ are different for each $x\in D$ as the intervals $I(x)$ are disjoint. Consider the set $R = \{r(x): x\in D\}$. Since it is a subset of $\mathbb Q$, the set $R$ is at most countable. Since $r:D\to R$ is a bijection between sets $D$ and $R$, $R$ is at most countable.

A good reference book would be *Convex Analysis* by R. Tyrrell Rockafellar for example.

Comment: Hey Pavel, thanks for your great answer. However, I'm afraid xou might habe to spell it out for me - when you say "each open interval contains a rational number" why does it follow that D must at most be countable? Aren't there irrational numbers in the interval too?

Comment: Hi I337n00b :), I eded the last paragraph to my answer that clarifies your question.

Comment: Theorem 25.5 in Rockafellar's book is the relevant result.